# Understanding Eliza Chatbot in prolog

Tags: dictionary, prolog, chatbot

I'm trying to understand how it really works the next eliza chatbot provided as example at:
https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/yet%20another%20eliza.pl

What I so far understand is, **that at the beginning we have a list (Dictionary) empty that will be fulfill with the matches of each word and each integer.**** The matching of words and integers will be performed through

```
match([N|Pattern], Dictionary, Target) :-
    integer(N), lookup(N, Dictionary, LeftTarget),
    append(LeftTarget, RightTarget, Target),
    match(Pattern, Dictionary, RightTarget).
match([Word | Pattern], Dictionary, [Word | Target]) :-
    atom(Word), match(Pattern, Dictionary, Target).
match([], _Dictionary, []).
```

**The matches will be saved in the dictionary through:**

```
lookup(Key, [(Key, Value) | _Dict], Value).
lookup(Key, [(Key1, _Val1) | Dictionary], Value) :-
    Key \= Key1, lookup(Key, Dictionary, Value).
```

I have been also reading the explanation found in the book "The art of prolog" of Leon Sterling and Ehud Shapiro but I can't really get it

I would appreciate your help

```
eliza :-
    write('? '), read_word_list(Input), eliza(Input), !.

eliza([bye]) :-
    write('Goodbye. I hope I have helped you'), nl.
eliza(Input) :-
    pattern(Stimulus, Response),
    match(Stimulus, Dictionary, Input),
    match(Response, Dictionary, Output),
    reply(Output),
    !, eliza.

match([N|Pattern], Dictionary, Target) :-
    integer(N), lookup(N, Dictionary, LeftTarget),
    append(LeftTarget, RightTarget, Target),
    match(Pattern, Dictionary, RightTarget).
match([Word | Pattern], Dictionary, [Word | Target]) :-
    atom(Word), match(Pattern, Dictionary, Target).
match([], _Dictionary, []).

pattern([i,am,1],[how,long,have,you,been,1,'?']).
pattern([1,you,2,me],[what,makes,you,think,i,2,you,'?']).
pattern([i,like,1],[does,anyone,else,in,your,family,like,1,'?']).
pattern([i,feel,1],[do,you,often,feel,that,way,'?']).
pattern([1,X,2],[can,you,tell,me,more,about,your,X,'?']) :- important(X).
pattern([1],[please,go,on]).

important(father).
important(mother).
important(son).
important(sister).
important(brother).
important(daughter).

reply([Head | Tail]) :-
    write(Head), write(' '), reply(Tail).
reply([]) :- nl.

lookup(Key, [(Key, Value) | _Dict], Value).
lookup(Key, [(Key1, _Val1) | Dictionary], Value) :-
    Key \= Key1, lookup(Key, Dictionary, Value).


read_word_list(Ws) :-
    read(A),
    tokenize_atom(A, Ws).
```

Comment: It would help if you could make clear what aspect you're trying to understand. Assume I enter "I am happy". Then `Input` will be `[i, am, happy]`. The matching `Stimulus` will be `[i, am, 1]`, matched with a `Dictionary` mapping `[(1, happy)]`. With the same `Dictionary`, the matching `Response` is `[how, long, have, you, been, happy, '?']`. What part of this causes you troubles?

Comment: Hi @IsabelleNewbie ,  thank you for your response. My doubt was actually as you pointed with the ```Dictionary``` and how the Integer was related to the Word  of ```Response```. After your answer I could related better with the Graphic Debug of Prolog